# Can i use Bundling [Bundle.Config] in .net 4 Asp.Net web Application

Tags: javascript, bundle, asp.net-4.0, bundling-and-minification

I have my application in .Net framework 4.It is a Asp.Net Web Application.i need to use Bundle.Config in order to use Bundling feature.

I have read many documents saying that, it is feature in .Net framework 4.5 and that to in Asp.Net MVC Application.

I need to make a bundle for Scripts in aspx pages.
Can i include Bundle.Config in my file so that Bundling works.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can use bundling in ASP.net 4. Use `Nuget Package Manager` to install `Microsoft ASP.Net Web Optimization Framework` to your project. Then in `global.asax` register the bundles in `Application_Start` method. something like this -

```
    var jqueryBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jquery");
    jqueryBundle.Include(new string[] { 
        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate-additional-methods.js"
    });

    BundleTable.Bundles.Add(jqueryBundle);
```

Then in your `aspx` page or `masterpage` call the bundle-

```
    <%= System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery") %>
```

Comment: i need to have http : //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js in bundle this code is not accepting this path as valid path

Comment: I don't think you can bundle a scripts that doesn't reside on your own domain.

Comment: @ th1rdey3 : refer to my solution you can refer to hosted js file in bundling

Comment: Hmm... `bundles.UseCdn = true`. I didn't know about this.

Answer (score 3):

Over couple trial and Reading Bundling i found the solution

Install Web Optimizer framework from NuGet package Manager for the solution include System.Web.Optimization in following file, even in Apsx file.

in Application_StartUp () :

```
 var bundles = BundleTable.Bundles;
 bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support
 var jqueryCdnPath = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js";
 var jQueryUICdnPath = "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js";
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",jqueryCdnPath)); 
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui", jQueryUICdnPath));
```

In Aspx page :

```
  <script src="<%=BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jqueryui")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<%=BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jquery")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

~/bundles/jqueryui : for UI java script 
~/bundles/jquery   : for functionality java script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add dll file WebGrease.dll in Reference
2. Add Bellow code for js and css in global.asax

   dynamic solutioncss = new System.Web.Optimization.StyleBundle("~/bundles/solutionDetailCSSBundle");
   solutioncss.Include("~/Style.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
   solutioncss.Include("~/incs/highslide/highslide.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
   solutioncss.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
   System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.Add(solutioncss);

   dynamic HeaderLinkBundle = new System.Web.Optimization.ScriptBundle("~/bundles/HeaderLinkBundle");
   HeaderLinkBundle.Include("~/js/jquery.js");
   HeaderLinkBundle.Include("~/js/headerlink.js");
   HeaderLinkBundle.Transforms.Add(new JsMinify());
   System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.Add(HeaderLinkBundle);

   System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
3. Add this bundle of css and js to aspx page.